# A graph with n nodes and n vertices can contain just one cycle

Tags: algorithm, nodes, graph-theory

If a graph unweighted `G` have the same number of `Nodes` and `Edges` , it is correct to assume that the graph `G` just contain one cycle ? Can be proved ?

EDIT: And all node are conected

Comment: This looks like a homework problem or test question.

Comment: Not precisely @chuckj is for a algorithm problem, the context is that i need to find several shortest paths on a spamming tree , but my graph maybe contain the same quantity of nodes and edges and i got a cycle so i had to get rid of that cycle and somehow keep the shortest paths. So i need to know if just one cycle or N cycles can exist

Comment: What is the difference between nodes and vertices in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and only if there are one component in a graph. In other words, if from each node, there is a path to any node in a graph, you can assume that there are exactly one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that all the nodes in the graph are connected. If the nodes in the graph are not connected, then answer to your question is no.

Also graph has to be a simple  graph(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)?oldformat=true#Simple_graph)